# Calling a custom dialog from FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I have a situation where I would like to to call the LocationControl (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/tree/master/CSharp) so the user can enter an address for a form (but would like to disambiguate the response using the control).

What would be the best way of doing this with FormFlow? The validate for the field doesn't give me the context so I can't do a 
    `context.Call(MyLocationDialogInstance)`

I tried to do it in a custom prompt but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide a code example?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?